# Is logit_bias disabled for gpt-4-vision model or is my code wrong?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-4

I have been using the combination of max_tokens=1 and logit_bias for text classification tasks on the OpenAI GPT-4 API. [Logit bias](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5247780-using-logit-bias-to-define-token-probability) makes it easy to nudge the model to only output certain words like yes or no, cat or dog, so it works like a classifier. This does not seem to work on the new gpt-4-vision-preview model however, which throws this error:

> Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': '1 validation error for Request\nbody -> logit_bias\n  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

This works fine on the gpt-4 model, and this code works fine with the vision model when the logit_bias is commented out (code below uses OpenAI's Python package). No difference if low or high detail. I've gone through the docs (it's the same chat completion endpoint as for gpt-4), googled the error and vision + logit_bias keywords and found no other posts on this issue.

```
import os
import base64
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key=YOUR_KEY) # needs key to run example

# Function to encode the image from OpenAI docs
def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
    return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

image_path = "path_to_your_image.jpg"
base64_image = encode_image(image_path)

result = client.chat.completions.create(
model="gpt-4-vision-preview",
messages=[
{
  "role": "user",
  "content": [
    {"type": "text", "text": "Does this image depict a cat, Yes or No?"},
    {
      "type": "image_url",
      "image_url": {
        "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}",
        "detail": "low"
      },
    },
  ],
}
],
temperature=0,
logit_bias={9642:100, 2822:100},  # <---- this guy here, tokens for Yes & No
max_tokens=1
)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not available for this model yet? If the latter, is there a workaround for image classification? Without the bias it's prone to respond like a chat model (which it is), e.g. instead of yes or no it will start saying "Sorry..." etc.